# DataTables - get values of a single column from all selected rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to retrieve the values from the first column of my DataTable, of all selected rows. So, the dev of DataTables suggests the following:

```
function getValues() {
    let rows = table.rows( { selected: true } );
    return table.cells( rows, 0 ).data();
}
```

That works fine if a single row is selected. However, if multiple rows are selected, the returned object is just empty.

Any ideas on how to solve that?

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [**cell-selector**](https://datatables.net/reference/type/cell-selector) documentation. You can pass almost anything than an API result set. For example pass the `nodes()` for your `rows` result set :

```
return table.cells( rows.nodes(), 0 ).data();
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/sozqjbLc/**

Answer (score 2):

try

```js
function getValues(){
  var ids = $.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
     return item[0]
  });
  return ids
}
```

Comment: Yes, I believe that work too (have not tried it though) there is many ways to achieve the desired result, datatables have helper methods like every(), filter(), flatten() as well.